# How can I print the status of an I/O port in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I want to see the status of the port, but the following code gives me an error.

```
int PIN25_state = digitalRead(25);  // Read PIN25
Serial.println("PIN25_state: ", PIN25_state);
```

The error I get is

> no matching function for call to 'println(const char [14], int&)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [Serial.print() documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print/). The parameters of the function `print()` is the same as `println()`.

Where the **first argument** is what you want to send through the serial port, and the second argument is the format like **HEX, BIN, DEC, etc...**

So what you are doing is wrong.

You should instead do:

```
int PIN25_state = digitalRead(25);  // Read PIN25
Serial.print("PIN25_state: ");
Serial.println(PIN25_state);
```

where `print()` will put the value in the same line without new line and `println()` will make it print and then go to new line.

Comment: Or in other words, it is not possible to output more than one data type at a time (string and number attempted in the question), thus the split into two function calls.